# Enrich mediator Invalid Object type to be inserted into message body

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

ERROR: Enrich mediator Invalid Object type to be inserted into message body

when trying to enrich the message, here is the proxy configuration:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Database" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>1234</password>
                  <user>root</user>
                  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_db</url>
                  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>select * from users where name="rik"</sql>
               <result name="client_expiration" column="expiration" />
               <result name="client_id" column="id" />
               <result name="client_name" column="name" />
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="returned value for client_expiration is :" expression="get-property('client_expiration')" />
            <property name="returned value for client_id is :" expression="get-property('client_id')" />
            <property name="returned value for client_name is :" expression="get-property('client_name')" />
         </log>
         <property name="property1" expression="get-property('client_expiration')" scope="default" />
         <enrich>
            <source type="property" property="property1" />
            <target type="body" action="sibling" />
         </enrich>
         <sequence key="getback" />
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

and the sequence configuration (but should not be here the problem):

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="getback">
   <header name="To" action="remove" />
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" />
   <send />
   <log level="full" />
</sequence>
```

Many thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**: the log works but the message doesn't. This is the log file:

```
[2012-09-03 09:44:28,853]  INFO - LogMediator returned value for client_expirati
on is : = 2012-08-30, returned value for client_id is : = 1, returned value for
client_name is : = rik
[2012-09-03 09:44:28,854] ERROR - EnrichMediator Invalid Object type to be inser
ted into message body
[2012-09-03 09:44:28,856]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPA
ction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:f0035921-8b6a-48db-a9a4-78be2687336d, Di
rection: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Enve
lope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body /><
/soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have enrich mediator like this and try

```
<enrich>
            <source type="custom" xpath="get-property('property1')"/>
            <target type="body" action="sibling"/>
        </enrich>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not change the error, I have posted the LOG if you want to have a look...