# wso2 esb enrich target xml node

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2-esb

I have an xml which is following structure

```
<XML><Payload><InXML></InXML><Endpoint><Response/></EndPoint>
```

i want to enrich this payload tag `InXML`, i have tried the following way but it seems it's failing and works only if we enrich the xml property/body as a whole, 
so it gets appended to `<XML>` tag as a child but not to `InXML`

Suppose the above xml is current set in body

```
<enrich>
<source type="property" clone="true" property="inputXML"/>
<target type="custom" action="child" xpath="//InXML"/>
</enrich>
```

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217227/enrich-mediator-invalid-object-type-to-be-inserted-into-message-body) as well but my case is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the inputXML as bellow before the enrich mediator, then make sure to define the type attribute as "OM".

Eg:

`<property name="inputXML" expression="//foo/bar" type="OM"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The selection of target action "replace" or "child" depends on the source type (when the defined property for the source isn't set with type="OM").

source is property:

`<source type="property" clone="true" property="inputXML"/>
<target type="custom" action="replace" xpath="//InXML"/>`

source is inline:

`<source type="inline" clone="true">
  <test>1234</test>
</source>
<target type="custom" action="child" xpath="//InXML"/>`